# ios Mapview properties are not persisting

Tags: ios, mkmapview, exc-bad-access

I am trying to use the `mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView regionDidChangeAnimated:(BOOL)animated` method to limit the region of my mapview but whenever I make a call to my mapview's region (`[self.userMapView setRegion:regionLimit]` ), it gives me a EXC_BAD_ACCESS error.

This error is thrown no matter what property I try to call from my mapView.  I have my mapview set to the mapview with a proper outlet, and I was even able to call the `set region` in the `viewDidLoad` message.

How can I keep these properties from throwing the bad access error?  If no can answer, can anyone direct me to a resource explaining how to debug something like this?  Thanks.

Comment: Ya but I haven't gotten the feel for them quite yet.  Could you briefly walk me through a process using intrumtents that could detect and solve this issue?

Comment: Once I do this, how do I interpret the info?  When I click it it doesn't say 'zombies', it says 'allocations' then gives me a list of the object usage stats.  Even if I were to track down what is happening, how would this help me fix it?

Comment: Nothing appears to be getting selected when it stops.  This may be because the mapview's properties are mainly all Structs and not objects.  the MKMapView itself remains active.

Comment: Not sure how that helps.  Forgive me I've only been at this for a few months ;)

Comment: I set up MKMapView *userMapView as instance variable and a `@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet MKMapView *userMapView;`  I will show the rest of the relevant code in these imgur links.
http://i.imgur.com/XoqYM.png
http://i.imgur.com/j2nS6.png

Comment: possible duplicate of [EXC_BAD_ACCESS with MKCoordinateRegion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9987368/exc-bad-access-with-mkcoordinateregion). Bro, it is bad form to double post a question.  if you need to push it to the top, offer a bounty.

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/qVKKO.png << Picture of when my allocations stop.  I also have a lot of MKPolygon code that I add as overlays to the map, but this problem has existed before any of that code was added.  I did not know about the bounty thing.  Ty will make sure it doesn't happen again

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/Jg3Wp.png << Example method that adds the polygons to the map (works fine) in case your curious

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [here](http://www.touch-code-magazine.com/how-to-debug-exc_bad_access/) for his to debug EXC_BAD_ACCESS errors and common mistakes that cause them.  In your case, I'll bet your property is long dead and recycled, or was never initialized in the first place.